# Android DefaultHttpClient.execute() not returns when using mobile network

Tags: android, networking

I have issue with using DefaultHttpClient. DefaultHttpClient.execute() not returns when I using mobile network connection.

This issue I have only on my device (Acer Liquid with OS LiquidNext 1.9.2), on other devices DefaultHttpClient.execute() works fine. When I use Wi-Fi connection DefaultHttpClient.execute() also works fine.

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(requestURL);
HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(request); // execution stops here, execute() not return a value and not throws a exception
```

Is it my programm bug, or LiquidNext bug?

The problem is in caching dns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392485/android-dns-caching

Comment: Never had any issue like this, and none of my users reported anything like that. Noone seem to use Liquid OS either.